# Jest module mock - doMock doesn't work as intended

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

I have a module that exports an object, let's call it `myObject`.

This export is used somewhere on the call-stack of the test case, but not *directly* in the test-case.

I would like to mock different values for this export depending on test cases.
Currently, the mock works if I have it top-level and use `jest.mock`:

`jest.mock('../myModulePath', () => ({myObject: {mocked: 'valueHere'}))`

However, using `jest.doMock` instead, while making sure to reset modules before each test with 
`beforeEach(() => jest.resetModules())` doesn't work.

I've tried using a `require` right after my `doMock` call but as expected it didn't work, as I'm not using the module directly in my tests.

Has anyone managed to achieve this?

Comment: I've faced an similar problem today as well. haven't found the perfect solution but probably this might help you. take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62304899/how-do-you-mock-a-default-exported-object-with-jest-per-test)

Comment: Please provide minimal code under test

Comment: Any progress on this one?

Comment: wouldn't a spy work better in your case? or maybe have the mocked value be a reference to a jest.fn() and then change the value on each test...