# how do you mock a default exported object with jest per test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm currently working on a test where I need to mock a default exported config object to test different configuration possibilities.

I've found a possibility to do this on file basis with `fetch.mock` but this doesn't give me the possibility to change the mock in each test run.

Is there something like `jest.mockImplementation` for a mocked Object or how does this work?

I've created a Repo with the example code: [here](https://github.com/takethefake/jest-mock-object)

Unit under test:

```
import * as React from "react";
import config from "./config";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {config.greet ? <h1>Hello user</h1> : <h1>Bye user</h1>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

config which should be mocked:

```
const config = { greet: true };

export default config;
```

What I want to test

```
import App from "./App";
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

/* 
I'm currently only able to mock on per file level but not on test level
jest.mock("./config", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: { greet: false },
}));
*/

describe("App", () => {
  it("renders hello if greeting true", () => {
    jest.mock("./config", () => ({
      __esModule: true,
      default: { greet: true },
    }));
    const { debug } = render(<App />);

    // should render 'Hello user'
    debug();
  });

  it("renders bye if greeting false", () => {
    jest.mock("./config", () => ({
      __esModule: true,
      default: { greet: false },
    }));

    const { debug } = render(<App />);

    // should render 'Bye user'
    debug();
  });
});
```

**EDIT 1**

I've found a kind of a workaround. If I do resetModules after each test and do the mock and afterwards do the loading of the Unit under test it is possible to get different values.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

describe("App", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
  it("renders bye if greeting false", () => {
    jest.doMock("./config", () => ({
      __esModule: true,
      default: { greet: false },
    }));

    const App = require("./App");
    const { debug } = render(<App.default />);
    debug();

    // should render Bye user
  });
  it("renders hello if greeting true", async () => {
    jest.doMock("./config", () => ({
      __esModule: true,
      default: { greet: true },
    }));
    // or when using import syntax
    const App = await import("./App");
    const { debug } = render(<App.default />);

    debug();
    // should render Hello user
  });
});
```

This works but I don't like the syntax of it. Can you think of a solution where I import App at the beginning of the file and just override the config object in the test? Because when I render more than one component I have to import all config dependant components in each test again. This doesn't feel right.

**EDIT 2**

I found a way to provide a overwritable mock on a global level. But i'm currently stuck getting the jest-mock function invoked.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
jest.mock("./config", () => jest.fn());
import * as config from "./config";
const mockConfig = (config as unknown) as jest.Mock;
import App from "./App";

describe("App", () => {
  it("renders bye if greeting false", async () => {
    mockConfig.mockImplementation(() => ({
      greet: false,
    }));

    const { debug, container } = render(<App />);
    expect(container.querySelector("h1")?.textContent).toBe("Bye user");
    //config is jest.fn()
    debug();
  });

  it("renders bye if greeting true", async () => {
    mockConfig.mockImplementation(() => ({
      greet: true,
    }));

    const { debug, container } = render(<App />);
    expect(container.querySelector("h1")?.textContent).toBe("Hello user");
    //config is jest.fn()
    debug();
  });
});
```

**EDIT 3**

I decided for now that I will provide a 'hook' which I can mock with jest.

```
const config = {
  greet: true,
};

export function useConfig() {
  return config;
}

export default config;
```

with this, I'm able to provide a custom mock for `useConfig` on a global level which I can override in each test call.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { mocked } from "ts-jest/utils";
jest.mock("./config", () => ({ __esModule: true, useConfig: jest.fn() }));
import * as config from "./config";
const mockConfig = mocked(config);

import App from "./App";

describe("App", () => {
  it("renders bye if greeting false", async () => {
    mockConfig.useConfig.mockReturnValue({
      greet: false,
    });

    const { debug, container } = render(<App />);
    expect(container.querySelector("h1")?.textContent).toBe("Bye user");
    //config is jest.fn()
    debug();
  });

  it("renders bye if greeting true", async () => {
    mockConfig.useConfig.mockReturnValue({
      greet: true,
    });

    const { debug, container } = render(<App />);
    expect(container.querySelector("h1")?.textContent).toBe("Hello user");
    //config is jest.fn()
    debug();
  });
});
```

Since this leads to a refactoring of all components that use the config I'm not happy with this as well and am still looking forward for a object-based mocking solution.

Comment: It seems like this is related to https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2582#issuecomment-583293933

Answer (score 7):

You can rather use a mock function for the manual mock of the config file and define its implementation directly before executing the test case like so:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";

const mockConfig = jest.fn();

jest.mock("./config", () => mockConfig);

describe("App", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
  it("renders bye if greeting false", () => {
    mockConfig.mockImplementation(() => ({
      __esModule: true,
      default: { greet: false },
    }));

    import("./App").then((module) => {
      const { debug } = render(<module.default />);
      debug();
    });

    // should render Bye user
  });
  it("renders hello if greeting true", () => {
    mockConfig.mockImplementation(() => ({
      __esModule: true,
      default: { greet: true },
    }));
    import("./App").then((module) => {
      const { debug } = render(<module.default />);

      debug();
    });
    // should render Hello user
  });
});
```

Note: The naming is essential here. You have to prefix your constant with 'mock' (mockConfig). Otherwise you will get an Error saying the variable is out-of-scope.

Comment: thanks for your input! this works quite well, but with this, I will receive a function instead of an object in the App component. I can make it work if I make the mock self-executable e.g.: `jest.mock("./config", () => mockConfig());`. But I still have to reimport App in each test case

Comment: With this, I get `ReferenceError: Cannot access <'mockConfig'> before initialization`. I'm presuming this is because Jest hoists `mock()` calls, so the const that you assign `jest.fn()` isn't available when the mock is being created. Any ideas on how to fix this?